# How do I test that a before_filter will redirect for all Rails controller actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, shoulda, before-filter

I have a fairly typical `require_no_user` as a `before_filter` in one of my controllers. I need to test that a logged in user is redirected by this filter if they try to access *any* of the controller's actions.

Is there a sensible way to do this without enumerating all of the controller's actions in my test case?

I'm trying to avoid:

```
context 'An authenticated user' do
  setup do
    activate_authlogic
    @user = Factory(:user)
    UserSession.create(@user)
  do

  should 'not be allowed to GET :new' do
    get :new
    assert_redirected_to(root_path)
  end

  should 'not be allowed to POST :create' do
    # same as above
  end

  # Repeat for every controller action
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of... though you could make it a bit shorter by packing all the methods and actions into a hash:

```
should "be redirected" do
  {
    :get => :new,
    :post => :create,
  }.each do |method, action|
    send(method, action)
    assert_redirected_to(root_path)
  end
end
```

Edit:  so yeah, this is probably overkill, but here's another way:

```
should "be redirected" do
  ActionController::Routing::Routes.named_routes.routes.each do |name, route|
    if route.requirements[:controller] == @controller.controller_name
      send(route.conditions[:method], route.requirements[:action])
      assert_redirected_to(root_path)
    end
  end
end
```

Seems though that if you define multiple :methods in custom routes that it still only "finds" the first, e.g.

```
map.resources :foo, :collection => {
  :bar => [:get, :post]
}
```

The above route will only be attempted with the GET verb.

Also if there are other requirements in the URL, such as presence of a record ID, my naive example ignores that requirement.  I leave that up to you to hack out :)

Comment: Thanks, that tidies it up a bit - but it still requires me to enumerate all the actions, which causes problems if I add new ones in the controller and forget to put them in the test.

Comment: As long as you've defined that filter without any `:only` or `:except` conditions, i.e. you're just using `before_filter :require_no_user`, I wouldn't worry about it.  The Rails core tests are responsible for proving that `before_filter` actually works.

Comment: That's right; it's a blanket `before_filter`. I guess I'm worried about an `:only` or `:except` argument being added down the track accidentally with no test case to catch this. Am I being too anal? I'm new to testing and still learning how to write sensible test cases. What do you think?

Comment: A simple comment in the controller `# don't add :only or :except !` would probably suffice, but I've added more to my answer for you to play with.